# How to create an anchor within a div?

Tags: anchor

I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require JavaScript, jQuery or anything too advanced; mostly HTML/CSS as those are what I am restricted to using.

The idea I have is a layout with two smaller div classes within one div ID. Each box have their own content and are placed side by side. What I'm trying to accomplish is to create an anchor link within one div that changes its content to something else.

e.g. box 1 on default displays "abc" as its content while box 2 displays "def". When you click on an anchor link in box 1, the content would then change to 123-- without affecting what's in box 2 or moving it down with the anchor.

Hopefully that makes sense.
There's no code to edit/work off of so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:target` selector to hide both div, and show element with the ID in the URL hash:

```
div.MyBox {
    display: none;
}
div.MyBox:target {
    display: block;
}
```

Clicking an `<a>` tag pointing to `#someId` would then show that element.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Would it be possible for you to show how it would appear for the HTML portion as well?

Comment: Do you mean having multiple (>2) divs, i.e. 1 with "abc", a hidden 2nd one with "123", and 3rd (visible) with "def"? I can't think of a better way to give the appearance of changing text without JavaScript, but it looks (if I understand you correctly) like more effort than not

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying to accomplish. It's not a matter of effort but what I am restricted to using. The site base I am trying to create this for doesn't allow JavaScript to be used.